# Unity Player's Shoot Function Will Not Work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in Unity. I have so far been able to get my player to follow the mouse at a somewhat correct angle. I am also trying to implement a shooting function for the character that shoots from the correct angle (straight from the top of the player, toward the mouse at the time of shooting). When I click using this code, nothing happens. I have objects set up for player, bullet and fire Point.

```
public void Update()
    {
        if (FollowMouse || Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            _target = Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            _target.z = 0;
        }

        var delta = ShipSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        var bulletDelta = shootSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        bulletDelta *= Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _target);

        if (ShipAccelerates)
        {
            delta *= Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _target);
        }

        angle = Mathf.Atan2(_target.y, _target.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _target, delta);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && Time.time > nextFire && numOfBullets > 0)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            Instantiate(bullet, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
            numOfBullets--;
            bullet.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(bullet.transform.position, _target, bulletDelta);

        }


    }
```